# How to update/remove old alarms?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a functionality in my app that creates alarm when it get data from the external API. when API data is refreshed, it again create alarms based on new data. Every time the user visit that specific view, the current data is pulled from the server and alarm is created. How can I ensure that the alarms created using old data get removed? The functionality is a kind of reminder service.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the same `requestCode` you used initially when creating the PendingIntent for your alarms if you used the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` or `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` to create additional alarms and it will cancel the alarm first and create a new one in the case of `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` or it will update the existing one with the new data in the case of `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

---

From the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, the current one should be canceled before generating a new one. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int, Intent, int).
>   You can use this to retrieve a new PendingIntent when you are only changing the extra data in the Intent; by canceling the previous pending intent, this ensures that only entities given the new data will be able to launch it. If this assurance is not an issue, consider FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT.

---

FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int, Intent, int).
>   This can be used if you are creating intents where only the extras change, and don't care that any entities that received your previous PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new extras even if they are not explicitly given to it.

---

Otherwise, you can cancel them yourself manually if those flags weren't specified. You just need the request code

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode, alarmReceiverClassIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (am != null) {
        am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
```